# alsa-util 1.1.0 arm cross compile issue

Tags: cross-compiling, embedded-linux, alsa

I am trying to build alsa-util-1.1.0 for an arm-linux platform, through trial and error I managed to compile alsa-lib and alsa-util ok using these commands:

alsa-lib:

`CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc ./configure --host=arm-linux -prefix=/home/username/20160311_alsa_work/alsa/install --disable-python`

alsa-util:

`CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc ./configure --prefix=/home/username/20160311_alsa_work/alsa/install --host=arm-linux --with-alsa-inc-prefix=/home/username/20160311_alsa_work/alsa/install/include --with-alsa-prefix=/home/username/20160311_alsa_work/alsa/install/lib --disable-alsamixer --disable-xmlto --disable-nls --disable-bat --with-udev-rules-dir=/home/username/20160311_alsa_work/alsa/install/lib/udev --with-asound-state-dir=/home/username/20160311_alsa_work/alsa/install/var/lib/alsa --disable-alsaconf`

This is quite similar to this guide: [Alsa audio cross compile and use](http://www.programering.com/a/MTN0UDMwATk.html)

The compilation seems ok and the `make install` puts everything in the right folders. I then copy all the libs and bins to my targets rootfs and try execute `arecord -l`

The output of arecord is:

`**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
ALSA lib conf.c:3750:(snd_config_update_r) Cannot access file /home/username/20160311_alsa_work/alsa/install/share/alsa/alsa.conf
ALSA lib control.c:954:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL hw:0
arecord: device_list:277: control open (0): No such file or directory`

There is obviously something wrong with my configure options but I cannot see any other way to change them... any ideas???

I need to cross-compile for my arm-linux target and install to the target's rootfs but have all the paths relative to root of the rootfs and not the prefix which should only be used for building.

For info:
I use the `--with-udev-rules-dir=` and `--with-asound-state-dir=` options because otherwise the install will try copy files to my build machines directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--prefix` must be the path as seen on the *target* device.

To install the files into a different path on the *host*, use `DESTDIR`:

```
make install DESTDIR=/home/me/whatever
```

Comment: Thank you so much - this worked great. For reference I ended up using a simplified configure string for alsa-lib and alsa-utils `CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc ./configure --host=arm-linux --disable-python

 
CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc ./configure --target=arm-linux --host=arm-linux --with-alsa-inc-prefix=/home/username/20160311_alsa_work/alsa/install/usr/include --with-alsa-prefix=/home/username/20160311_alsa_work/alsa/install/usr/lib --disable-alsamixer --disable-xmlto --disable-nls --disable-bat`
 
For both I used ` make install DESTDIR=/home/username/20160311_alsa_work/alsa/install`

Answer (score 0):

I can cross-compile with alsamixer enabled, of course, ncursesw needs to be installed in the sysroot.
If of any use, this are my config flags

```
-exec-prefix=/usr --datarootdir=/usr/share --includedir=${DIR_DIST}/targetfs/usr/include --with-alsa-prefix=${DIR_DIST}/targetfs/usr/lib --with-alsa-inc-prefix=${DIR_DIST}/targetfs/usr/include
```